# cross compile embedded arm

Tags: kernel, embedded, make, arm

I have the android 4.2.2 code in directory `/home/sghPhone2` which compiles normal with `make menuconfig` but I need to compile a 4.4 kernel and possibly patch it but when I download the source from google, nothing in it looks normal:

```
darknet064tokyo WORKING_DIRECTORY # ls /home/WORKING_DIRECTORY/
Makefile  bootable  developers   external    libcore          packages   system
abi       build     development  frameworks  libnativehelper  pdk        tools
art       cts       device       hardware    ndk              prebuilts
bionic    dalvik    docs         kmake       out              sdk
```

then command `ANDROID_JAVA_HOME=/home/jdk1.8.0/ make menuconfig` ends with:

```
including ./tools/external/fat32lib/Android.mk ...
make: *** No rule to make target `menuconfig'.  Stop.
```

and pointing crosscompile from my 4.4.2 directory

```
/home/WORKING_DIRECTORY/gcc: No such file or directory
```

I acquired the source from [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), and
I am really confused how to compile this new kernel.
I followed the direction on building, but of course the device failed to boot when flashed. because of incorrect drivers.
Where is the kernel config?

Comment: What you have here is the source code for the whole Android system. Did you try to compile the whole of it, or just the kernel? In what directory did you run `make menuconfig`? Do you have an arm cross-compiler already set up? Depending on your phone model, the Google source code may or may not support all your hardware; you may need to get a kernel with additional driver from the phone or processor manufacturer. In any case the Android source treee isn't the easiest way to compile just the kernel. What phone model do you have?